# HTTPS redirecton causes error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I have no forms and logins in my site, but my site automatically redirecting to `https://`. How can I resolve this?? I am using `.htaccess` file.

```
ErrorDocument 400 /ErrorPages/HTTP400.html
ErrorDocument 401 /ErrorPages/HTTP401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /ErrorPages/HTTP403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /ErrorPages/HTTP404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /ErrorPages/HTTP500.html
ErrorDocument 501 /ErrorPages/HTTP501.html
ErrorDocument 502 /ErrorPages/HTTP502.html
ErrorDocument 503 /ErrorPages/HTTP503.html

Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^paulnmartin.com [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.paulnmartin.com/$1 [R=301,L]  
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

[image: Connection error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...but my site automatically redirecting to https://. How can I resolve this??

The following two directives in your `.htaccess` file are causing this redirect and should therefore be removed if you don't have an SSL cert installed.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

If this has been in place for "a while" then this goes some way to explain what you are seeing in the Google SERPS, as stated in your other question posted on Pro Webmasters:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112095/why-is-google-indexing-my-site-in-https-how-to-change-it-into-http

Consider adding the reverse redirect to fix any indexing issues:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !off  
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

(However, it may take some time for search engines to correct this.)